# Validation in Struts - iterating text filed

Tags: validation, struts, struts-validation

I am iterating text field in struts. while performing validation the property of the text field is not getting idetified.

```
<logic:iterate id="tSMultiplier" name="tForm" property="tSMultiplierList" indexId="i" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="tForm_savings_${tSMultiplier.desc}">${tSMultiplier.desc}:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <html:text name="tSMultiplier" property="savingsPct" indexed="true" styleId="tForm_Savings_${i}" size="6" ></html:text>
        % </td>
    </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

I need to validate property - savingsPct as integer.
Here's validation.xml snippet

```
<field property="savingsPct" depends="integer">
                <arg position="0"  key="label.savingsPct"/>
</field>
```

I m getting following error

```
org.apache.commons.validator.util.ValidatorUtils getValueAsString Unknown property 'savingsPct' on class 'class com.tForm'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**savingsPct** should have a getter in the class **com.tForm**. Then the error will not come.

Answer (score 0):

Since I m validating by iterating the list, in validation.xml added the attribute for `<field>` tag

```
indexedListProperty="tSMultiplierList"
```